# Why does ConvertFrom-Json produce an Object which turns into a PSCustomObject after assignment? And how do I shortcut that?

Tags: json, powershell

I have a simple json file as follows:

```
[
    {"ClientName": "Test Site 1", "ClientID": "000001"},
    {"ClientName": "Test Site 2", "ClientID": "000002"},
    {"ClientName": "Test Site 3", "ClientID": "000003"}
]
```

When I use the following PowerShell command:

`ConvertFrom-Json (Get-Content TestSites.json -Raw)`

I get back a `System.Object[]`.  This doesn't allow me to pipe the output to another function I have which accepts "ClientName" and "ClientID" parameters.

However, when I assign that object to another variable, like this:

`$myobj = ConvertFrom-Json (Get-Content TestSites.json -Raw)`

`$myobj` is actually a `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` which is capable of being passed to my function.

How can I just pipe the results of the original command without having to assign it to another variable first?

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What is your powershell Version. I get `objects[]` for both cases `(ConvertFrom-Json $json).gettype().fullname;$obj = ConvertFrom-Json $json;$obj.GetType().FullName`. The answer is PowerShell unrolling the array in the pipe. Someone should have a good answer though

Comment: I see his issue and I am using PowerShell v5.

Comment: I get System.Object when using GetType() on them both, but piping to Get-Members shows them as different object types.  The PSCustomObject is the one I can use as it has my properties.

Comment: _piping to Get-Members_ you still get unrolling so be careful of the conclusions you draw from that. Again you will see a difference with `(Convert...) | gm` and `Convert... | gm`. `Get-Member` does have an `-inputobject` parameter which you can use in _some cases_ to skip the piping and therefore this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON is an array correct? PowerShell will unroll arrays in the pipeline unless you explicity change that behavior. Assuming your JSON is stored in the variable `$json` as a single string consider the following examples.

```
ConvertFrom-Json $json | ForEach-Object{$_.gettype().fullname}
System.Object[]

(convertFrom-Json $json) | ForEach-Object{$_.gettype().fullname}
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

You should be able to wrap the expression in brackets to change the outcome. In the second example it should be sending the 3 objects individually down the pipe. In the first it is being sent as a single object array.

My explanation needs work but I am sure of the cause is how PowerShell deals with arrays and the pipeline. Unrolling being a common word used to describe it.

So depending on your use case you might just be able to wrap the expression in brackets so it gets processed before the pipe to `ForEach` in my example.

Comment: That is crazy... So, yes, this works: `(ConvertFrom-Json (Get-Content TestSites.json -Raw)) | MyFunction` but this does not `ConvertFrom-Json (Get-Content TestSites.json -Raw) | MyFunction`

Comment: Oh, I see... I think I get it now, thanks... I'd almost expect it to be the other way around whereby it passes three objects along if we're parsing as we go rather than sending the whole thing by surrounding it in brackets, but I guess in surrounding with brackets, it knows what it has before it starts sending it along?

Comment: When using the brackets it forces PowerShell to complete the expression before sending anything down the pipe. Without it Powershell will attempt to send each object it gets down the pipe (Which is usually preferable).

Comment: Does that mean that ConvertFrom-Json isn't processing the objects correctly as it should send them down individually without having to force completion of the expression?

Comment: As far as I can tell `ConvertFrom-JSON` is doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing. Your process needs different results from what normally happens is all.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array such as `System.Object[]` you could try piping via `foreach`:

```
ConvertFrom-Json (Get-Content TestSites.json -Raw) | %{ $_ | your-function }
```

If you want to pass the whole array down the pipe as-is, you can try adding a comma (aka a [unary comma](https://becomelotr.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/unary-comma/) before the variable:

```
,$myobj | whatever
```

You can probably see how the latter works by comparing the following:

```
$myobj | Get-Member            # Shows the type of the elements of the array
Get-Member -InputObject $myobj # Shows the type of the array
,$myobj | Get-Member           # Shows the type of the array
```

Comment: Thanks.  The point is I don't want to assign it to $myobj.  Having $myobj works since that object has my properties which I can pass along the pipeline.  I just wouldn't have expected assigning the commands to a variable to have changed the object type?

Comment: Sorry, meant to avoid using the variable in my answer. Still might not be addressing your question properly though. Hmm.